# How to fix 'Request error : authentication failed empJAgent.exe' error in Oracle loading test?

Tags: testing, load, oracle-apps

I'm trying to make my first load adf test. I have chosen software from Oracle "Oracle Application testing suite". But after probably first good test everything that I'm trying to test receives an error response even empty scenario ( of course from open script).

I tried lots of combinations in settings in `OpenScript` and all of the requests in this app are passed. We can find errors only in Oracle Load tests app. I don't have any idea what should I do. Can you give me any advice?

Every request responds showing this error:

```
Request error : authentication failed empJAgent.exe
```

Comment: please add code so that other can understand the problem, without code it is difficult to help

Comment: The Oracle Load Testing shows only this single error as a response after starting correct test.